# Updating child in firebase not working as expected

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data into firebase, by first generating a child using .childByAutoId() and then update the child with the necessary data. But it doesn't seem to work as expected.

The structure I am trying to achieve is

```
events
  attendees
   -L0P1D5arR0OkBf8h
      userEmail: "user@user.com"
      userName: "User name"
      userPhone: "0864567182"
```

Here's what I have done so far:

```
    guard let fee = events?["eventFee"] else {
        return
    }
    guard let key = events?["eventKey"] else {
        return
    }
    guard let eventTitle = events?["title"] else {
        return
    }

    if fee == "0" {
        var values = [String: String]()


        self.ref = Database.database().reference()

        let attendeekey = ref.child("events").child(key).child("attendees").childByAutoId().key

        let userDetails = UserDetails()

        for user in userDetails.currentUserDetails {
            guard let userEmail = user.email else {
                return
            }
            guard let firstName = user.firstName, let lastName = user.lastName else {
                return
            }
            guard let userPhone = user.phoneNo else {
                return
            }

            let userName = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"

            values = ["userEmail": userEmail, "userName": userName, "userPhone": userPhone as! String]
        }

        ref.updateChildValues(["events/\(key)/attendees/\(attendeekey)": values], withCompletionBlock: {
            (err, ref) in

            if err != nil {
                self.displayAlertMessage(message: err as! String, title: "Oops!")
                //print(err ?? "An error occured")
                return
            }

            let message = "You have successfully registered for \(eventTitle)"

            self.displayAlertMessage(message: message, title: "Success!")

        })
    }
```

Is anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: What is happening instead of what you expected?

Comment: Nothing, 
the child doesn't get created in my database, and its not due to network, 'cos i checked that over and over to be sure.

Can there be any reason why that will happen?

Comment: Well without seeing the `UserDetails` object, it's hard to know, but it looks like the code initializes a `UserDetails` object here `let userDetails = UserDetails()` but doesn't populate it with anything, so if the initializer doesn't include user details, the code would stop at the guard statements. If  you put in breakpoints, can you see if `updateChildValues` gets called?

Comment: have you checked that *values* has anything inside or is empty when updating child value?

Comment: SO `attendeekey` is gets a valid ID and only the update fails, or this step already fails?

Comment: @JenPerson the `updateChildValues` gets called

Comment: @AndrasM. `attendeeKey` gets a valid id, but I dont even see the id in my database

Comment: The whole thing is very confusing to me...

Comment: I just noticed that, when I put a break point at `let attendeekey = ref.child("events").child(key).child("attendees").childByAutoId().key` i get a warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available. and another error: `2017-12-20 12:09:13.271848+0100 Konnect[647:206346] XPC connection interrupted`.Please does anyone know what that means?